# How to print data of array of array object in view

Tags: laravel

I have an array of array object data but I am getting an error when I try to print this in view. Here is my data:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [user_id] => 4 [user_name] => Infinity Resort [listing_name] => 200 Hour Yoga Teacher Training [course] => 200 Hour Yoga Teacher Training [course_duration] => [retreat_type] => Featured [start_date] => [end_date] => [last_day_to_register] => [contact_person] => Infinity Resort [website] => http://bookyogatrips.com [contact_number] => 265478541 [address1] => Kathmandu ,Bagmati Nepal 4460 [address2] => [country] => Thailand [country_id] => 217 [state] => Bangkok [state_id] => 3528 [city] => Bangkok [pincode] => 44600 [rooms_type] => [overview] =>
hjkhjkhj

[program_description] =>
kjhkjhkhj

[curriculum] =>
hjkjhk

[why_choose] => [area_destination] =>
hkjhkhjk

[location] => [about_food] =>
hjkjhkjhk

[program_special] => [inclusions] => [food] => Vegetarian,Vegan [accommodaion_image] => [currency] => [itineraries] => [local_info] => [weather_information] => [seasonal_information] => [meta_title] => [meta_description] =>
hkjhkjhkh

[meta_keyword] =>
ghjghj

[service_type] => Yoga TTC [course_cat] => 2 [media] => 101839ManasluTrek.jpg [approved] => 1 [created_at] => 2018-11-14 10:41:50 [updated_at] => 2018-11-14 10:41:50 [_token] => ) )
```

How can I print this data in a Laravel view?

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: Can you share view file code or given error?

Comment: yes sure... i have put my controller code after aarray data..please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's array of objects  then you can give a try like below code:

```
foreach($arrayObjects as $object){
     ...
     $object->id; 
     $object->user_id; 
     ...
 }
```

Comment: Good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code

```
foreach ($objdata as $data) {
    $data = (array) $data
    // now $data is array 
}
```